# Сортировка двумерного массива java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Three {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num[][] = {
            {5, 4, 45, 12},
            {7, 5, 8,  85},
            };
    Arrays.sort(num);
    for(int row = 0; row<2; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col<4; col++){
            System.out.print(num[row][col]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Выдает ошибку. Одномерный массив таким образом сортировался, что не так?

Comment: Эээ... А как вы хотите отсортировать двухмерный массив? Что должно получиться в итоге?

Comment: Сортировка по возрастанию. От меньшего значения к большему. В данном случае что-то вроде 4, 5, 5, 7...

Comment: И чтобы перепаковало массив?

Comment: Да, (тут просто символы для того чтобы коммент пропустило...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам придётся вручную перепаковывать массив в «плоский».

Например, так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Three {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num[][] = {
            {5, 4, 45, 12},
            {7, 5, 8,  85}
        };

        int[] flat = new int[2 * 4];

        int ctr = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                flat[ctr++] = num[row][col];
            }
        }

        Arrays.sort(flat);

        ctr = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                num[row][col] = flat[ctr++];
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                System.out.print(num[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/50oR4z

Comment: @Alex78191: Хм, и как тогда отсортировать? Не соображу что-то. Напишете ваш вариант?

Answer (score 3):

А я бы добавил сюда немножечко стримов

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Three {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num[][] = {
                {5, 4, 45, 12},
                {7, 5, 8,  85},
        };

        int[] numTemp = Stream.of(num).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sorted().toArray();
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                num[row][col] = numTemp[row * 4 + col];
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                System.out.print(num[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сортировка вида

```
Arrays.sort(num);
```

работает только с одномерными массивами.

Чтобы отсортировать двухмерный массив по горизонталям, нужно прописать конструкцию вида:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
    Arrays.sort(num[i]);
}
```

В итоге получим:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Three {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num[][] = {
            {5, 4, 45, 12},
            {7, 5, 8,  85},
            };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        Arrays.sort(num[i]); //проходим по горизонталям массива и внутри 
                             //горизонталей осуществляем сортировку
    }

    for(int row = 0; row < num.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < num[i].length; col++){
        
        /*
        num.length возвращает количество строк массива
        num[i].length возвращает количество элементов в i-той строке
        */

            System.out.print(num[row][col] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).